# Depicting the Jewish wedding

Tags: marriage, wedding, pictures

Is it considered sacrilegious to paint a picture of the chuppah in one's future wedding before the actual ceremony? Therefore, can the artist portray his/her upcoming wedding scene without the chuppah?

Comment: Hello Sarah! Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Thanks for bringing your question here. Do you mind explaining why exactly you think this might be considered sacrilegious?

Comment: P.S. you don't happen to be Noah Winkler's sister Sarah, do you?

Answer (score 2):

It's not considered a sacrilege to paint a picture of the *chupa* in one's future wedding. Nor to paint the wedding scene without the *chupa*. Source: I've been around a little and have never heard of such a thing; and [*Nit'e Gavriel*](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/46545) and [*Taame Haminhagim*](http://hebrewbooks.org/14556) don't mention it AFAICT.

Comment: Had this been me you would have not allowed to let this one pass!

Comment: I could see it as a little weird or tacky - "here's what I think my wedding will look like when I meet Mister Right" -- and when the right time comes, G-d willing, please realize that things don't always play out as you'd fantasized they would; but no there's no law or custom against drawing weddings!

Comment: @yehuda, this answer? I agree it's not the best answer, and I might well not have upvoted it if another posted it, but I would certainly have "let this one pass". What's wrong with it?

Comment: @msh210 I would have been downvoted for no source! No worries, just pointing it out!

Comment: @yehuda, not by me.